# APEX JOB TO DELETE RECORDS

Tags: apex, class, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

I have a demand and I need help to create an apex that is in Batch and delete all accounts with more than 10 years on the platform. I managed to get to the code below but I can't advance can someone help me?

```
public with sharing class DeleteRecordsJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {
  private final String query;
  
  public DeleteRecordsJob(String query) {
    this.query = query;
  }
  
  // Schedulable method
  public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    Database.executeBatch(new DeleteRecordsJob(query));
  }
  
  // Database.Batchable methods
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }
  
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<sObject> scope) {
    delete scope;
  }
  
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
  }
}
```

with this query to delete the records.

```
DeleteRecordsJob j = new DeleteRecordsJob('SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate < LAST_N_YEARS:5');
```

Comment: Are you hitting a problem? Do you have some other problem? Please ask something specific.

Comment: Where do I put this query SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate < LAST_N_YEARS:5 to delete the records in this class?

Comment: I tried private final String query = 'SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate < LAST_N_YEARS:5'

Comment: But It didn't function!

Comment: After the job ran this error apears in the console: Scheduler: failed to execute scheduled job: jobId: 7076w00000Szyoe, class: common.apex.async.AsyncApexJobObject, reason: Final variable has already been initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to replace your Schedulable Method with something like this ?

```
// Schedulable method
public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    Database.executeBatch(this);
}
```

Indeed, a "Final" variable can only be set once, and you create two instances of your class, so you try to set to the final two times.

Instance one :

```
DeleteRecordsJob j = new DeleteRecordsJob('SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE LastActivityDate < LAST_N_YEARS:5');
```

Instance two :

```
// Schedulable method
  public void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    Database.executeBatch(new DeleteRecordsJob(query));
  }
```